# Optimizing SQL inserts for a third party ETL program

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert, etl

We have a vendor currently in house that has a custom built ETL package (it's part of a larger program) that seems to be taking a very long time to complete.

Our current setup is running SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition.  There are two servers involved, the SQL Server and another server known as the batch server.  Essentially what happens is the Batch server makes a request of the SQL Server for a set of rows from a table, it stores these rows in memory on the Batch server and it goes through several transforms here.  Once the data is transformed/scrubbed, it then needs to be loaded back into several different tables on the database server.  This is currently being done via a series of insert statements wrapped up in a SP_PREPARE.  It then proceeds to run the sp_execute statement once for each row that needs to be inserted (tens of millions of times).

It's been a while since I've used IBM Datastage, but I seem to remember it tried to do these inserts similarly by default and was horribly slow as a result.

I've mentioned having them export a datafile with the modified data and allowing us to bulk import this file, but exporting the data to a file would supposedly take a significant change to their code and is likely not an option.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Andrew

Comment: If your current vendor's entire process is designed around what is probably the least efficient way to perform this operation, it may be time to find another vendor...

Comment: Believe me, I've suggested that more than once!  Thank-you for confirming my fear!  :-)

Comment: ha, `significant change to their code`, in their loop to call each sp_execute each row, just write to  a file

Comment: I totally agree KM!  It shouldn't be rocket science to make such a change.  I was mostly just trying to see if there were any other ideas on how to efficiently get the data back in the database since I was running out of ideas.  I just got off of another project in the last two months where the vendor had been doing a similar task with a cursor in the database, at least I was able fix their code myself, this one all the logic of their job is in a java program on another server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo JNK's comment above. There's not a heck of lot you can do without changing the code, but one thing you can do is drop the indexes on the target before the insert and rebuild them afterward. Rebuilding the index after each row may be substantially slowing the process down.

Comment: Thanks Chris, we had a discussion with the vendor yesterday and had offered that up as a potential improvement (it should save on IO at least during the inserts).  However, it gets better, the tables they are inserting into are fairly narrow, maybe 10 columns total of which there are 4 non-clustered indexes, one being a unique index, but no clustered index!  We're still waiting for answers on this one, but I didn't want to confuse my post further than i already had  :-)

Comment: That's brutal. The only other suggestion I have (which I didn't offer for fear of ending up massively voted down) is to throw hardware at it.

Comment: Well, they've decided to live with the performance rather than modifying the code, thank-you all for your comments and if nothing else, confirming my fear.

Answer (score 0):

If they are using the OLEDB Destination control, there are a couple of things that affect Insert speed:

1. Set it to Fast Load and push any
   duplicates (via Error Output) to an
   overflow table that can be
   re-inserted using regular table
   load. Normal speed load is at least
   2 orders of magnitude slower that
   Fast Load.
2. Set the
   DefaultBufferMaxRows on the Task
   control higher to bulk insert more
   items in a batch. However, even 1
   duplicate in a batch forces the
   whole batch to the Error Output.